# OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory - error AADSTS90009

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to authorize access to our web application by using OAuth 2.0 and Azure AD. Guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code).

The user is redirected to similar URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
    client_id=d220846b-1916-48d2-888b-9e16f6d9848b&
    response_type=code&
    response_mode=query&
    state=[secure-random]&
    redirect_uri=[my_uri]&
    resource=[my app ID uri taken from app settings]
```

I'm getting the following error then:

> AADSTS90009: Application 'd220846b-1916-48d2-888b-9e16f6d9848b' is
>   requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if
>   resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier.

This description does not really help me. I've checked this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3de0c14d-808f-47c3-bdd6-c29758045de9/azure-ad-authentication-issue-aadsts90009?forum=WindowsAzureAD#cf3986f5-3422-44d1-bcb7-3a4201f68fa2(I), but I'm still lost.

What does this error mean and which is the GUID based App Identifier? How should the value of the resource look like? Help much appreciated.

Comment: In my case, I am hosting the client and API on the same app service.
I got the error because I was using the .default scope. I had to define my own scope in order for it to work.

Comment: @Silvan where did you specify that scope? I'm trying to get the same scenario working.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Go to the App Registrations of your API -> Manage -> Expose an API

Comment: Actually I just found my mistake. I used `api://<client-id-guid>` as the resource instead of just `<client-id-guid>`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This error is saying that the field you provided in the `resource` parameter is requesting tokens for itself.  In the case you do want to get a token for the app specified in the client_id, then you have to pass the client_id in the resource field rather than the app ID URI.  At which point you will receive an access token for self.

Alternatively, you can provide an app ID URI of a web API you've registered or another resource with scopes to get tokens for that resource (Microsoft Graph, Office API, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused indeed - I intended to use the Microsoft Graph so this should have been my resource. I got my token now. Thanks again!

Comment: Much Thanks, saved my 4 hours at least

Comment: Likewise, it was very satisfying to find your answer after a few hours of debugging on a Sunday. Mixed emotions though; I don't know why the heck it doesn't work with the Application URI (in the same way as graph.microsoft.com - for example) because URI and client ID are both unique. Anyway, regardless - you're a champion, thanks.

Comment: Changing the value for 'resource' from the App ID URI to the client_id worked for me. But I don't understand why. I also can't find any documentation about that approach. Can I get some more info?

Comment: @Captainlonate out of curiosity, what type of app did you register: Web App/API or Native?

Comment: "Web app / API"

Comment: I'm still getting this issue with the v1 OAuth2 endpoints.  My URL that is redirected to is: