# What's the main reason of AADSTS90009?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

In this post,

[AAD token: Why aud sometimes shows app id, sometimes it's the app url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213979/aad-token-why-aud-sometimes-shows-app-id-sometimes-its-the-app-url)

I learn why the aud field in AAD token is sometimes app id, sometimes app url. They seems depend on what you put as resource when requesting token.

But, while I'm experimenting requesting an AAD token for a SPA website with app url (the SPA website's AAD app url), it returns AAD error - AADSTS90009.

> AADSTS90009: Application '' is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier.

See this post for related discussion.

[OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory - error AADSTS90009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006468/oauth-2-0-and-azure-active-directory-error-aadsts90009)

**I'm curious, what is the main reason behind this error?**

**Why it cannot support app url as resource identity?**

Comment: Requesting an access token for yourself kind of doesn't make sense. Typically you would want to request for a token for some API application.

Comment: I don't agree. For a website requires user identity, you need an token from AAD to represent the user. It doesn't necessary related to calling other APIs. If it doesn't make sense, why you can still get a token by replacing app url to app id?

Comment: That's an id token. You can get that by enabling implicit grant flow. But if you want to get it this way, you'll just have to specify the client id for the resource instead of the app id URI :)

Comment: Thanks, I will read more about the difference of id token and access token. But the tokens I got with adal.js for my portal, it has both. Btw, I would like to know why client id can be used in this case rather than app id uri? They both should be the identities of an AAD app.

Comment: Honestly I don't know why it is required that you use the client id instead of the URI :/

Comment: I just found I gave the wrong link for details of AADSTS900009 (updated the content). I did read the post before asking question here. Feel like my question is different than that post. If you agree, could you please remove the dupe comment? So other people might be able to read this question and maybe we can get someone who knows the reason to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are leveraging AAD and you get a token where **aud** claim contains:

- a Uri - it means you are dealing with access_token and the Uri
  represents Service Principal Name (read 'unique identifier') of the resource application your client application wants to access.
- a Guid - it means you are dealing with id_token and the value corresponds to ObjectId of that app which acquired the token.

Comment: I have to extend my answer: if your resource app is Microsoft First Party Application then the value for 'aud' claim could be a Guid even for access_token but if you are dealing with regular application then a Guid cannot be set for the app's IdentifierUri. But regular applications don't necessary will have Uri there - non Uri values cannot be set if Azure Portal is used but can be set through Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets.