# How does the consent flow determine which resources to ask for?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a multi-tenant service principal that exposes a custom API. Using MSAL.js' UserAgentApplication I'm able to ask for consent for the resources I need on first-time use with loginPopup. However, I'm confused as to which resources to specify in the request. For instance, let's say I use the following popup (note the lack of scope):

```js
await this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup({
    prompt: 'consent',
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"
})
```

The application will simply request the user's profile. Fair enough.

However, let's say I configure the popup as follows:

```js
await this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup({
  scopes: ["api://xyz/Some.Scope"]
  prompt: "consent"
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"
})
```

This causes an exception:

> The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx' named 'XYZ'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Why do I get this error even when I'm logging in using a Global Administrator account?

Lastly, in addition to our own API data we needed to be able to read Graph Groups in application context, so I requested these using the .default endpoint (permissions are specified in the Service Principal registration). I did this using the following popup:

```js
await this.userAgentApplication.loginPopup({
    scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
    prompt: 'consent',
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"
})
```

The result of the last attempt was ... all the permissions I was hoping for!

> Sign in and read user profile
>
> Read and write all groups
>
> My Custom API scope (Application name)

But why does our Graph consent request automatically include requests for other custom scopes?

Comment: Have you specified any required permissions in your app registration?

Comment: You could also try using the specific scopes in the last one instead of .default since it triggers v1 behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour if you use admin consent for the resources.

When you set `***/.default` as the scope, it is equivalent to executing "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" in Azure portal.

So it will asks admin consent for all the required permissions no matter whether they are from the required resource or not.

But if you set `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`, it will ask you to do consent only for `user.read` permission.

So in this case, once you use the last one to do the admin consent, `api://xyz/Some.Scope` will also take effect.

I also have a test with my custom API `api://***/.default` and `api://***/user.write` and both work as expected.

You can also try to use the following request to do the admin consent:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/jmaster.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect url}
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xyz/Some.Scope
&state=12345
&prompt=consent
```

Please have a retry with `api://***/.default`. Don't worry if it doesn't work, because `api://xyz/Some.Scope` will also take effect using the last code snippet.

Comment: Thanks! Your argument regarding the application requesting "full" permission when using .default makes sense to me. However, will requesting consent with .default for the custom API even work when there are also delegated permissions involved (not just application)? I tried and got the following error:

"Application [...] is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier."

Comment: Update: Based on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006468/oauth-2-0-and-azure-active-directory-error-aadsts90009) I realized that when requesting admin consent for the entire custom API you have to use the app ID, not the api:// url. So in my loginPopup I had to provide _scopes: ["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/.default"]_ instead of _scopes: ["api://"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/.default"]_.