# Multitenant API - Admin consent ERROR https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent AADSTS90009

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-service-principal

Using the following endpoint acting as the Admin on the tenantB I want to register a multitenant API App defined in another tenantA:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantB}/v2.0/adminconsent?
client_id={GUIDAppIDInTenantA}
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/myredirecturi
&scope=api://{GUIDAppIDInTenantA}/.default
```

I am getting this error:

> AADSTS90009 Application is  requesting  a  token  for  itself.  This
> scenario  is  supported  only  if  resource  is  specified  using  the
> GUID  based  App  Identifier

I am using the GUID based App Identifier from TenantA. I get the login page and after signing in, I am immediately redirected to the redirect_uri with the error above.

The post
[OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory - error AADSTS90009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006468/oauth-2-0-and-azure-active-directory-error-aadsts90009)  uses a different endpoint and mentions using the GUIDs that I am already using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the ‘openid profile’ scope like this
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/secondTenandID/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id={APP_IP}&redirect_uri={redirect_URI}&scope=openid+profile`

This will register the APP (and trust the main Tenant)

Second, submit another request with the actual Multitenant API scope using this format

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/secondTenandID/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id={APP_IP}&redirect_uri={redirect_URI}&scope={APP ID}/.default
```

this way the APP will be registered with the whole scope of permissions from the main tenant in the secondary tenant.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`&scope=api://{GUIDAppIDInTenantA}/.default`

with

`&scope={GUIDAppIDInTenantA}/.default`

Comment: After following your advise I am getting this error: "The app needs access to a service (AppID multitenant app) that your organization {tenantB} has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions". I am the admin in TenantB using the adminconsent endpoint. The APP is configured as a multitenant with "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs", what else has to be configured?

Comment: Try provisionating the MT app in tenant b: `New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId <tenant a app id>`

Comment: I had another open issue, as the powershell approach is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

All you need is **&scope=.default**
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ConsentingTid}/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id={WebOrSpaAppId}&redirect_uri={RedirectUri}&scope=.default](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BConsentingTid%7D/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=%7BWebOrSpaAppId%7D&redirect_uri=%7BRedirectUri%7D&scope=.default)

No need to spell out the app id twice.

If all you are doing is getting consent for you API, you will only need to consent once.

Also, in your MSAL2 client code:

```
interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: [
          '.default'
        ]
      }
```