# OAuth2 v2.0 authorize - error AADSTS90009 Application is requesting a token for itself

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Requirement:
Use OAuth2 Implicit Grant flow do authorization in swagger ui page.

Swagger configuration code:

```
  @Bean
  public Docket createRestApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("*"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
        .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
  }

  private SecurityScheme securitySchema() {
    String scopeForAppIdUri = "http://xxxxxxx/.default";
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScopeForAppIdUri = new AuthorizationScope(scopeForAppIdUri, "scope to restrict access to data protected by APIs");
    List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopes = Collections.singletonList(authorizationScopeForAppIdUri);

    LoginEndpoint loginEndpoint = new LoginEndpoint("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize");
    List<GrantType> grantTypes = Collections.singletonList(new ImplicitGrant(loginEndpoint, "Authorization"));

    return new OAuth("oauth2", authorizationScopes, grantTypes, null);
  }

  private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
    List<SecurityReference> securityReferences = Collections.singletonList(
        new SecurityReference("oauth2", new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope}));
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(securityReferences).build();
  }
```

Sent request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?response_type=token
&client_id={client id GUID}
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html
&scope=https://xxxxxxx/.default
&state=xxxxxxxxx
```

Error:

```
AADSTS90009: Application is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App identifier
```

**Question:**

There's a similar question about this error: [OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory - error AADSTS90009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006468/oauth-2-0-and-azure-active-directory-error-aadsts90009), which suggests to set 'resource' parameter to be client id for v1.0, so for v2.0, it can clear the error by setting 'scope' value to be client id.

**But** for my case, Our endpoints will validate 'aud' value in token that should equals to the application id uri 'http://xxxxxxx'(this feature cannot change), which means i cannot just set 'scope' to be '{client-id}/.default', or else even though it can return token successfully but the token cannot pass the validation of endpoint.

Comment: If you can only accept one valid audience value, one option could be to configure your app to accept v2 access tokens (access token accepted version in manifest set to 2). In those tokens the audience is always the client id regardless which is used to acquire the token in my experience.

Comment: @juunas I may not express my requirement clearly, i need the 'aud' in the returned token to be app id uri "https: //xxxxx" instead of client id